# ¿Cómo puedo agrupar el resultado de una búsqueda a una tabla base en Genexus?

Tags: foreach, genexus, genexus15, genexusxev3

Tengo la tabla base ventas la cual contiene fecha de venta, marca, monto. La recorro de la siguiente manera:

```
for each ventas
 where FechaVenta=&fecha
  &montoTotal=&montoTotal+ monto  
endfor
```

Con esto logro obtener el total del monto por día; pero necesito obtener el monto por marca y fecha, y el resultado sea mas o menos así:

```
Fecha     Marca  - Monto
01/12/21   VW       =900,000,000.00
01/12/21   Nissan   =200,000,000.00
01/12/21   Ford     =900,000,000.00
```

De antemano GRACIAS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los podes hacer anidando For Each y haciendo cortes de control

```
For Each Ventas
    Order FechaVenta
    Where FechaVenta=&fecha

    For Each Ventas
        Order Marca

        &MontoPorMarca = 0

        For Each Ventas
            &MontoPorMarca = &MontoPorMarca + monto
            &montoTotal=&montoTotal+ monto  
        EndFor

        PrintBlock Fecha Marca MontoPorMarca

    EndFor

    PrintBlock MontoTotal

EndFor
```

La navegacion debe mostrarte siempre recorridos sobre la tabla ventas, mostrando los anidados como "break"

Answer (score 0):

Cómo podría traducir el siguiente código de *SQL GeneXus*:

```sql
SELECT
    PD.CONCEP_CVE_RECIBO PER_CPTO,
    CONCEP_ABREVIACION PER_ABRE,
    CONCEP_PER_DEDUC PRE_PD,
    SUM(PERDED_IMPORTE) PER_IMPORTE
FROM
    sc_pens_nominas nom,
    SC_PENS_PER_DEDUCCIONES PD,
    SC_PENS_CONCEPTOS CON
WHERE
    nom.nomina_fecha = to_date('28/02/2023')
    AND nom.pat_num_patente = PD.pat_num_patente
    AND nom.nomina_fecha = PD.nomina_fecha
    AND CON.CONCEP_CVE_RECIBO = PD.CONCEP_CVE_RECIBO
    AND nom.PAT_NUM_PATENTE IN (
        SELECT PA.PAT_NUM_PATENTE
        FROM
            sc_pens_dat_gens ge,
            sc_pens_patentes pa,
            sc_pens_nominas nom,
            sc_pens_situacion_pagos si,
            sc_pens_nominas_rnc rnc
        WHERE
            nom.nomina_fecha = to_date('28/02/2023') 
            AND nom.stpag_cve IN (7)
            AND nom.stpag_cve = si.stpag_cve
            AND ge.sol_num_solicitud = pa.sol_num_solicitud
            AND pa.pat_num_patente = nom.pat_num_patente
            AND pa.tpopen_cve <> 'IPP'
            AND nom.pat_num_patente = rnc.pat_num_patente
            AND nom.nomina_fecha = rnc.nomina_fecha
            AND NOMRNC_STATUS = 'NC'
            AND nomina_suspendido = 'N'
    )
    AND CONCEP_PER_DEDUC = 'P'
    GROUP BY PD.CONCEP_CVE_RECIBO, CONCEP_ABREVIACION ,CONCEP_PER_DEDUC;
```

Llevo horas intentando hallar una lógica sencilla para resolverlo, pero no tengo ni idea de cómo sacarlo.

Comment: Mas que una respuesta tu estas planteando una nueva pregunta. Este no es el sitio para hacerlo, deberias abrir una pregunta.